# Event.prevent for parent but not for child li

Tags: navigation

i've got a 3 level navigation and the event.preventDefaul(); should only effect the first level of the navigation but it effects all 3 levels, how can I change that?

### JS code

```
var $topLevelItems = $("nav > ul > li");
    $topLevelItems.click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {

            $topLevelItems.removeClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2')
                .slideUp('slow');

            $(this).addClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2').fadeIn('slow')
                .slideDown('slow',function(){
                    $('#nav').animate({height:$topLevelItems.find('.level_2:visible').height()+55},200);
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you click on a child item, the event propagates and triggers the click handler on the parent. You can either add a child click handler, and use `event.stopPropagation()`, or, in your parent click handler compare `e.target` against `this`, if they don't match, `return`

Comment: Can you help me with that event.stopPropagation()? Because it took me hours to create this code above.

Comment: I've posted an answer, hope it helps

Comment: Could you have a look at my answer?

Comment: You'll need to provide your markup. Looks like you're not clicking directly on the list element themselves, but a child (I'm guessing an anchor), which is why it doesn't work

Comment: Is is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DvG6H/5/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48965/discussion-between-billyonecan-and-fr3d)

Answer (score 0):

When i try this, the function doesnt start:

```
var $topLevelItems = $("nav > ul > li");
    $topLevelItems.click(function(event) {
            if (this !== event.target) { 
            return; 
            event.preventDefault();
            }
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {

            $topLevelItems.removeClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2')
                .slideUp('slow');

            $(this).addClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2').fadeIn('slow')
                .slideDown('slow',function(){
                    $('#nav').animate({height:$topLevelItems.find('.level_2:visible').height()+55},200);
                });
        }
    });
```